# How can I change my FF number on Iberia/British Airways to American Airlines?

Tags: loyalty-programs, british-airways, iberia

I booked a flight from Buenos Aires to London through Iberia (one of the legs is via British Airways). When I get to fill my personal information, the frequent flyer number is already filled with my British Airways number (on all the flights for both airlines) and I can't change it... Does anybody know if there a way to change it (to AA) online without having to ring customer service?

Comment: Try using the Finnair website's Manage My Booking, that often lets you change the FF details on other OneWorld airline bookings

Comment: Have you tried using BA's Manage My Booking?  If the flight currently has your BA number, it should show up when you log in to Executive Club, and from there you should be able to select MMB and then change the FF number  (It's been a couple years, but I have on occasion needed to change flights from my BA number to my AA number in order to be able to select seats.  BA's MMB let me change my FF number, and once I did, let me change seats.)

Answer (score 6):

If you booked the flight with British Airways or Iberia (or another airline who uses the Amadeus computer system), you can use the PNR (the alphanumeric reference  number you were given) to examine your booking via the websites of Finnair, Royal Jordanian or Qatar Airways.

The reason is that, their websites are just a front for the underlying Amadeus computer system (that BA also uses). Those three carriers have decided to expose more functionality through the website: any of those three will let you change the frequent flier number.

Qatarairways.com is probably the least "buggy" for this exact purpose (believe it or not).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I believe TAP Portugal uses Amadeus, and I had to call to add my US Airways numbers to the reservation.

Comment: Sounds like a useful tip.  I wonder if this should be in a wiki or someplace as a general tip?

Comment: Thanks for this! Some sites (including this) mention using Finnair for this purpose, but that no longer works -- Qatar still does.

Unfortunately somehow Alaska Airlines is not listed as an option, so I'm going to end up collecting miles with American Airlines after all.